# How to understand the `version` of `Both Windows and macOS implement their own version of code signing.`?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

When I read this document [electron-glossary](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/glossary):

> Code signing is a process where an app developer digitally signs their code to ensure that it hasn't been tampered with after packaging. Both Windows and macOS implement their own version of code signing. As a desktop app developer, it's important that you sign your code if you plan on distributing it to the general public.

How to understand the `version` of `Both Windows and macOS implement their own version of code signing.`?

why don't say:

```
Both Windows and macOS implement their own code signing.
```

Comment: Straight dictionary meaning "a particular form of something that is slightly different from other forms of the same thing:" (Cambridge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code signing is a concept. Both Windows and macOS want to employ this idea. But they have different visions on how to implement it. They will have different versions of it.

Answer (score 0):

A subtle difference: "implement their own code signing" would be interpreted as "code signing is a generally available feature, but Windows and macOS implement their own, different code signing". That is not the case.